# Hibernate: Getting org.hibernate.InstantiationException While Fetching polymorphic Collections in onetomany association

Tags: java, hibernate, polymorphic-associations, joined-subclass

I am trying to use JOINED inheritance strategy in Hibernate using JPA annotations. My Base class is abstract and have Many to One association with other entities. However I am getting Hibernate Exception: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface. 
Following is my class structure:

Account.java

```
@Entity(name="BANK_ACCOUNTS")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Account {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ACC_ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="account_id_seq", sequenceName="BANK_ACCOUNT_ACC_ID", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="account_id_seq")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="IS_ACTIVE")
    @Type(type="yes_no")
    private Boolean isActive;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ACC_BRANCH_ID")
    private Branch branch;
}
```

SavingsAccount.java

```
@Entity(name="BANK_SAVINGS_ACCOUNT")
public class SavingsAccount extends Account{

    @Column(name="CURR_BAL")
    private BigDecimal currentBalance;
}
```

Branch.class

```
@Entity(name="BANK_BRANCH")
public class Branch {

    @Id
    @Column(name="BRANCH_ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="branch_id_seq", sequenceName="BANK_BRANCH_BRANCH_ID", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="branch_id_seq")
    private Long id;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="branch",orphanRemoval=true, fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade(value=org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Account> accounts = new HashSet<Account>(); 
}
```

So whenever I try to get list of accounts held by branch using the following code I get the exception mentioned below:

```
Branch branch = (Branch) session.get(Branch.class, branchId);
SavingsAccount acc = new SavingsAccount();
acc.setBranch(branch);
branch.getAccounts().add(acc);
```

Exception trace:

```
org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface:  : com.sapient.bank.entities.Account
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.instantiate(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:737)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.instantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4761)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.instantiate(SessionImpl.java:1427)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.instantiate(SessionImpl.java:1415)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.hydrateEntityState(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:693)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1933)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:559)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:555)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$3.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$3.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readElementExistence(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.add(PersistentSet.java:200)
    at com.sapient.bank.dao.AccountDao.createNewSavingsAcc(AccountDao.java:28)
    at com.sapient.util.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:32)
```

Please help me understand what is wrong with my code. Its working fine if I remove abstract keyword, but I want to make Account class as abstract. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I am having 3 Tables in my DB corresponding my class structure: Account, Branch, SavingsAccount.

Answer (score 0):

You could try for the following syntax in **Branch**  Entity if you would like allow **SavingsAccount** or **Child of SavingsAccount**:

```
 @Cascade(value=org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
 private Set<? extends Account> accounts = new HashSet<SavingsAccount>();
```

If you would like to add all future Sub Object of Account, then

```
 @Cascade(value=org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
     private Set<? extends Account> accounts = new HashSet<Account>();
```

Comment: If I do this, then I won't be able to maintain associations with any future account subclass like: LoanAccounts. Branch can hold both savingsAccount and loanAccount.

Comment: Does the above configuration fix the exception org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface:  : com.sapient.bank.entities.Account that  you got?

Answer (score 0):

You should make the `Account` class a `MappedSuperclass` instead of an `Entity`. I didn't try it, so let me know, but that's how you deal with abstract classes with JPA annotations.

Reference: [The Java EE 6 Tutorial 
: Entity Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html)